# Parse 2 records into one and join tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Reviewed

```
    +----+--------------------- +------+-------+
    | id |   POS  |  Review Date| Role |app ID |
    +----+----------------------+------+-------+
    |  1 |   A    | 2018-12-03  |  E   |  170  |
    |  2 |   A    | 2018-12-04  |  P   |  170  |
    |  3 |   B    | 2018-12-01  |  E   |  180  |
    |  4 |   B    | 2018-12-05  |  P   |  180  |
    |  5 |   B    | 2018-12-05  |  X   |  190  |
    |  6 |   B    | 2018-12-05  |  w   |  195  |
    |  7 |   C    | 2018-12-06  |  w   |  170  |
    +----+--------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Call_Center

```
    +----+------+-----+------+
    | id |  POS |  Emp|  yrs |
    +----+------+-----+------+
    |  1 |   A  |  F  |   4  |
    |  2 |   B  |  F  |   3  |
    |  3 |   C  |  P  |   3  |
    +----+------+-----+------+
```

Need Call Center joined; also, forgot that there can be many roles(x, w, u, t), but just interested in combining reviewed date for Roles E and P.

Need to return one record for each unique POS, including both review_dates for ONLY roles E and P; only app id 170; EMP and yrs from call_center, joining on POS

For example:

```
POS Review_Date(role E) Review_Date(role P) EMP Yrs app ID
A   2018-12-03          2018-12-04           F   4   170
```

See updated tables

Oracle syntax please

Comment: On which database engine? Oracle, MySql, SqlServer, ...?

Comment: Why would you join `Call_Center`? It adds no additional information to your result.

Comment: For simplistic sake, I did not add all columns for Call_Center :)

Comment: Oracle dbms please

Comment: Where are you getting `2018-05-04` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `case when` to filter the dates matching the desired role, and combine that with a `group by` (and `max`):

```
select Pos,
       max(case Role when 'E' then review_date end) review_E,
       max(case Role when 'P' then review_date end) review_P
from reviewed
group by Pos
```

You can also use the `pivot` clause available since Oracle 11g:

```
select *
from (
    select Pos, Role, review_date
    from reviewed
)
pivot 
(
    max(review_date)
    for Role
    in ('E', 'P')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use two CTEs:

```
with
e as (
  select * from reviewed where role = 'E'
),
p as (
  select * from reviewed where role = 'P'
)
select
  coalesce(e.pos, p.pos) as pos,
  e.review_date as review_date_role_e,
  p.review_date as review_date_role_p
from e
full outer join p on e.pos = p.pos
order by coalesce(e.pos, p.pos)
```

Comment: Ignore the last comment ..suppose to be in description

Comment: @javaCoder The query is in Oracle syntax. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.POS, A.review_date as review_date1, a.ROLE as ROLE1, B.review_date as 
review_date2, B.ROLE as ROLE2
from reviewed a
left join reviewed b
on a.POS = b.POS
and a.review_date < b.review_date
where B.ROLE is not null
;
```